# implicit @requestParam doesn't work on spring boot 3.x or above?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm testing @RestController.
In the Controller, I wrote two methods mapped to HTTP GET Request.

one explicitly using @RequestParam annotation to let spring framework know which query parameter should be mapped to which method parameter,
and the other doesn't use @RequestParam annotation so that spring infers by using parameter names.

the result is only first method works, and the other doesn't.

is this because spring boot 3.x doesn't support this used case anymore?

```java
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/request-param-v3")
    public String requestParamV3(
            @RequestParam("username") String username,
            @RequestParam("age") int age) {

        log.info("username={}, age={}", username, age);
        return "ok";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/request-param-v4")
    public String requestParamV4(String username, int age) {
        log.info("username={}, age={}", username, age);
        return "ok";
    }
```

only requestParamV3 works.
requestParamV4 returns Whitelabel Error Page.

below is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'hello'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: solved!
the problem occured because of the absence of -parameters option in javac compiler.

FYI, I work on IntelliJ IDEA CE and using IntelliJ to complie and build instead of Gradle.